# iOS - Cannot get SMXMLDocument to work

Tags: ios, xml, sdk

Im using a xmlparser called `SMXMLDocument`. https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument

I use `NSURLConnection` and `NSURL` to fetch the `XML` down and that works fine. I can log it in the console.

Now it is time to get the elements inside a string and i use this code.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn 
{
    NSString *fetchedXML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedXML);

    [xmlData release];
    xmlData = nil;

    [connection release];
    connection = nil;

    [self performSelector:@selector(parseXML)];

}

-(void)parseXML
{

    SMXMLDocument *document = [SMXMLDocument documentWithData:xmlData error:nil];

    SMXMLElement *content = [document.root childNamed:@"content"];


    for (SMXMLElement *name in [content childrenNamed:@"name"])
    {
        NSString *name = [name valueWithPath:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"name:%@", name);
    }
}
```

This is apparently not working and i don't get a log with the name element. My xml code is very simple and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<content>
<name>John Doe</name>
</content>
```

Can anyone help me with why this is not working. 
Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
 SMXMLElement *content = [document.root childNamed:@"content"];
```

try

```
 SMXMLElement *content = document.root;
```

Because "content" element is the root of your document :)

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
SMXMLDocument *document = [SMXMLDocument documentWithData:xmlData error:nil];

NSString *content = [[[document.root childNamed:@"content"] childNamed:@"name"] value];

NSLog(@"name:%@", content);
```